# Projections on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

My question is:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T \in B(H)$. Prove that $T$ is a
>   projection if and only if $T$ is the identity on the orthogonal
>   complement of its kernel.

Thanks

Comment: Probably orthogonal projection.

Comment: Do you need some other property, like self-adjoint?

Comment: I assume "$T$ is a projection" is defined to mean "$T = T^*$ and $T^2 = T$."  In this case, here is a hint (mainly for the "if" direction, which is the harder one): for any $A$ in $\mathcal{B}(H)$, the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $A$ is the closure of the range of $A^*$.

Comment: I know what you say.

Comment: @leslietownes: If $T^*=T$ and $T^2=T$, then $T$ is an orthogonal projection (which is indeed what the question should specify).

Answer (score 3):

If "projection" is changed to "orthogonal projection", then here are some hints.

**Hint 1:** $\ker(T)^\perp=\{u\in H:Tx=0\Rightarrow \langle u,x\rangle=0\}$

**Hint 2:** Any $v\in H$ can be written as $v=u+k$ where $u\in\ker(T)^\perp$ and $k\in\ker(T)$.